# How do I fix the Vue error in ERPNEXT during file upload?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, erpnext

I have a problem on erpnext when I tried to upload image in course error appears in console as

> Vue warn : property or method "__"  is not defined on the instance but referenced during render make sure that this property is reactive

I tried to change permission to root but no result

Comment: Please share a bit of example some code to us, so we can properly help you.

Comment: I did not write any code I just use ERPNEXT File upload to upload image for course module and vue should load file uploader form from FIleUploader.vue but the error accrues

Comment: Then this is the wrong platform here developer support other developer. 

Please check out the Documentation and go to Erpnext support / customer care

Doc: https://docs.erpnext.com/homepage

Contact: https://erpnext.com/contact-form/new